# How to prevent rebuilding of dependency in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I have a project like this:

```
mre
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── PRIMARY
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── inc
│   │   └── PRIMARY.h
│   └── src
│       └── PRIMARY.c
└── SECONDARY
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── lib1
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── inc
    │   │   └── lib1.h
    │   └── src
    │       └── lib1.c
    └── lib2
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── inc
        │   └── lib2.h
        └── src
            └── lib2.c
```

When I start build of `PRIMARY`, first `SECONDARY` target is built (all its libraries), which are copied to `libs` folder after the build.
Then `PRIMARY` is starting to build, but `SECONDARY` libs are building again. How can I avoid rebuilding of `SECONDARY` libs (`lib1` and `lib2`)?
[image]

Root CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15 FATAL_ERROR)

set(CMAKE_ROOT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

project(my_project)

add_subdirectory(SECONDARY)
add_subdirectory(PRIMARY)


add_custom_target(ALL_TARGETS)
add_dependencies(ALL_TARGETS
SECONDARY
PRIMARY
)
```

PRIMARY CMakeLists.txt:

```
link_directories(${CMAKE_ROOT_DIR}/lib)
add_executable(PRIMARY)

add_dependencies(PRIMARY
  SECONDARY
)

target_link_libraries(PRIMARY
                      lib1
                      lib2                 
)

target_include_directories(PRIMARY PUBLIC
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/inc
)

target_sources(PRIMARY PUBLIC
${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/PRIMARY.c
)
```

SECONDARY CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_subdirectory(lib2)

add_custom_target(SECONDARY)
add_dependencies(SECONDARY
  lib1
  lib2
)

include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib1/inc
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib2/inc
)
```

lib1 CMakeLists.txt:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(lib1 STATIC)

set_target_properties(lib1
  PROPERTIES
  ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_ROOT_DIR}/libs
)

target_include_directories(lib1 PUBLIC
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/inc
)

target_sources(lib1 PUBLIC
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/lib1.c
)
```

lib2 CMakeLists.txt:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(lib2 STATIC)

set_target_properties(lib2
  PROPERTIES
  ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_ROOT_DIR}/libs
)

target_include_directories(lib2 PUBLIC
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/inc
)

target_sources(lib2 PUBLIC
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/lib2.c
)
```

PRIMARY.h and PRIMARY.c

```
#ifndef PRIMARY_H
#define PRIMARY_H


#endif // PRIMARY_H
```

```
#include "PRIMARY.h"
#include "lib1.h"
#include "lib2.h"

int main()
{
    lib1();
    lib2();
}
```

lib1.h and lib1.c

```
#ifndef LIB1_H
#define LIB1_H

void lib1();

#endif // LIB1_H
```

```
#include "lib1.h"

void lib1()
{

}
```

lib2.h and lib2.c

```
#ifndef LIB2_H
#define LIB2_H

void lib2();

#endif // LIB2_H
```

```
#include "lib2.h"

void lib2()
{

}
```

**EDIT**: Added minimum reproducible example.

Comment: The code and explanations in the question post are too imprecise. Please, provide [mcve].

Comment: @Tsyvarev I added now the example.

Comment: `target_sources(lib1 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/lib1.c)` - That way `lib1.c` becomes **source** not only for the `lib1` library, but for `PRIMARY` executable too, because it links with `lib1`. You need to change `PUBLIC` to `PRIVATE` for avoid such behavior. (Usually, `target_sources` is used exactly with PRIVATE keyword.)

Comment: @Tsyvarev That was the problem! Thanks!